# How to change the Event name of a session in AppSee from an iOS application?

Tags: ios, appsee

Does anyone know, how to change the event name on Appsee? I am able to update the screen name using AppSee delegate method. But when I am using the add event operation, it's adding a separate event on Appsee session. I don't want to add a new event name. I would like to upgrade the auto generated event name with my custom event name.

Any idea if there is any iOS Appsee API available to do that. There is no documentation on Appsee that how to change a auto generated action event name.

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to are **"actions"** in the Appsee terminology, and cannot be modified. You can contact their support so they disable the auto recognition of actions and then you can manually add the custom ones you'd like.

Comment: I don't think, it's gonna work. Their application video session tracker automatically detect each user's action event over the app.

Comment: Appsee support only can remotely disable automatic event detection. I am 100% sure of this, I am a developer in Appsee.

Comment: Sounds great. But I don't want to disable automatic event tracking. i would like to change the name of the event instead of auto generation. Just like today we can change the screen name by using Appsee delegate method.

Comment: @SalehSultan Unfortunately that is not possible.